# Logging source IP for connection through SNI proxy

Tags: ssl, https, sni

I'm using a simple SNI proxy ([slt](https://github.com/inconshreveable/slt)) to forward HTTPS to the correct virtual machine without terminating SSL in the proxy.

Something that is glaringly obvious in hindsight: there is no way for me to find out and log the source IP address of that connection, as the proxy cannot add an `X-Forwarded-For` header. Is there an equivalent mechanism in SSL that would allow the proxy to indicate that the connection was forwarded?